# Run npm and node from ansible

Tags: node.js, npm, ansible, zsh

I have a machine that has zsh installed.
I created the following script to make some installs:

**Installs made**

```
# Install NVM
sudo curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
## Reload shell to start using nvm
. ~/.zshrc
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 0.12
```

Now I want to connect to the instance and run ansible-playbook that will start the following script:

**sh-script.sh**

```
npm install aws-sdk


node create-queue.js $machine_name
node create-queue.js $machine_name
```

When running the playbook I get the following errors:
line 28: npm: command not found --
line 32: node: command not found --
line 33: node: command not found.

When I ssh to the instance and run "node" or "npm" I get valid response and desired condition.
The ansible-playbook is very simple:

**ansible**

```
- hosts: tag_Name_TestInstance
  tasks:
    - name: Run Script
      shell: /home/ubuntu/sh-script.sh '{{ machine_name }}'
```

Answer (score 4):

the best way IMHO to solve this is to add an additional bin  path to the ansible env.

```
  - name: Install aws-sdk
    command: /opt/node/bin/npm "something"
    environment:
      PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:/opt/node/bin"
```

or you could use the native ansible npm function

```
   description: Install "aws-sdk" node.js package.
  - npm: name=aws-sdk path=/app/location
    environment:
      PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:/opt/node/bin"
```

and two other tasks to run the node js script. That way you could have also more info about what is going on.

good luck

Comment: Thanks @nelasx Works like a charm!! ;D

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because npm and node have not been added to your `$PATH`. The shell module will use `/bin/sh` to run your command.

If you want to run the script in zsh, try adding the shebang with the path to your zsh installation eg: `!#/usr/local/bin/zsh`